# Alternatives to tight_layout()

Tags: python, matplotlib

Calling [`tight_layout()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout) in matplotlib [can lead](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2654) to: `RunTimeError: "CGContextRef is NULL"`. I have suffered from this error myself with several backends (including `Agg`) in MacOSX and Linux.

If I want to achieve the same, or hopefully close enough, effect, without running into these errors, what are my options?

Answer (score 4):

While not the same problem, I worked around issues I was having with `tight_layout()` by adding this to the start of my script instead.

```
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
```